# header("Content-Type": "image/jpeg") for Swagger UI.

Tags: javascript, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a scenario where I need to upload an image through POST request. There is no issue when I use Postman client to send the requests. I need to use Swagger UI to test the API call and I am not able to send the image.

I have tried changing the parameter values in the swagger.json file to accommodate this, but all my attempts were futile.

Currently, I am trying to change the `swagger-ui.js` file. Upon looking the file, I found this -

```
request.types = {
  html: 'text/html',
  json: 'application/json',
  xml: 'application/xml',
  urlencoded: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'form': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'form-data': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
```

There is no request type to handle `image/jpeg` or any other file type apart from the 6 above given request types.

I also found the part of code where `multipart/form-data` is handled.

```
var isMultiPart = false;
if(headers['Content-Type'] && headers['ContentType'].indexOf('multipart/form-data') >= 0) {
    isMultiPart = true;
}

if (hasFormParams && !isMultiPart) {
    var encoded = '';

    for (key in formParams) {
      value = formParams[key];

      if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
        if (encoded !== '') {
          encoded += '&';
        }

        encoded += encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
      }
    }

    body = encoded;
  } else if (isMultiPart) {
    if (opts.useJQuery) {
      var bodyParam = new FormData();

      bodyParam.type = 'formData';

      for (key in formParams) {
        value = args[key];

        if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
          // required for jquery file upload
          if (value.type === 'file' && value.value) {
            delete headers['Content-Type'];

            bodyParam.append(key, value.value);
          } else {
            bodyParam.append(key, value);
          }
        }
      }

      body = bodyParam;
    }
}
```

I also tried adding `isImageJpeg` value to handle images. I am not able proceed since I have no prior experience in JavaScript. Is there a way by which I can similarly add a condition which can handle uploading of images?

Comment: How is your request supposed to look like, e.g. when using `curl`? Also, can you post your Swagger spec (.json/.yaml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7) Swagger follows prohibits any description of HTTP payload (by the `consumes` parameter) other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and/or `multipart/form-data`.

One of the reasons for this is that you shouldn't rely on your client for supplying the [correct MIME type](https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/15/whatsapp-telegram-vulnerability-account-take-over/) for an uploaded file.